# Ember-CLI: Initializers and Initializer subclass

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Currently, in Ember-CLI an Initializer is defined like so:

```
// app/initializers/observation.js
export default {
  name: 'observation',
  initialize: function() {
    // code
  }
};
```

in this case, how would I define a sub-class of that Initializer... is the following code correct?

```
// app/initializers/close-observation.js
export default Ember.Observation.extend{
  newProperty: 1,
  otherProperties: 2
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just import the base initializer into a variable and extend from that.

```
 import Observation from './observation';

 export default Observation.extend{
   newProperty: 1,
   otherProperties: 2
 };
```

Comment: Thanks again @blessenm, I'm starting to see the full picture of this whole import/export pattern.